# Is OAuth 2.0 required for accounts.locations.reviews.list "My Business API"?

Tags: reactjs, rest, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I have a React Application which is going to leverage Google My Business API to get review data of a business.

I was expecting to use the API-KEY via REST approach however [Authorization Scope](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews/list#authorization-scopes) mentions that OAuth 2.0 is required to use this API.

After I read more about OAuth's purpose, it seemed like it is more for application's which require access to a user's data and therefore would required a consent screen verified by google.

For my use-case however, all I need is access to all google reviews for a business and nothing related to the visiting users.

Can someone recommend an approach for this? (I don't want a pop-up/consent request when a user visits as I don't need user data.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much research, it seems that if you want to retrieve ALL REVIEWS for your business you will have to use Google's My Business API. This API **requires** you to use OAUTH2 for authentication which means (although you will not be querying a visiting user's data) visiting users will be required to provide consent pop up screen.

This leaves you with the places API as the next best option:

REST GET endpoint `maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid={your place ID}&fields=review&key={YOUR API KEY}`

Although this only returns google's top 5 "most helpful" reviews, its pretty much the only way to get reviews without a consent screen **unless** you want to scrape data which is not ideal for many reasons...

Comment: We ended up changing our requirement to show the latest 5 reviews and then added a link to google maps location to "View all" the reviews.